# TypeError: $(...) is null error for included JS file on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I am newer with javascript. I added some javascript code for autosuggestion. For this included some js files in template file.

When I provide some keyword, autosuggestion list populate properly but not showing item after selecting it and showing error "TypeError: $(...) is null".

This error not occurred for js code on template file. It is found for js file included in template fil.

I try to resolve conflict using "jQuery.noConflict()" but issue not solved.  It found very difficult to solve conflict for included js file.

Comment: I guess you're using the jQuery ui, are you sure that jQuery is loaded first, then jqueryui and then your code? You only need jquery.nocoflict if you are running different versions of jquery on the same page.

Comment: If I include jQuery, then it totally stop to work and not showing any activity. Also if add to jQuery and resolved to conflict, showing same error.

Comment: Someone has removed a very importaint tag from your post, are you using zend framework mvc? And adding jquery in the following way: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zendx.jquery.view.html If so then please add the zend framework tag again and hit the person that removed it with a rolled up newspaper.

Comment: Yes, I am using Zend framework but files are not included in way that you given. Please check comments for following answer.

Answer (score 0):

Removed comments revealed that the following autocomplete files were used: http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/

This is not a jquery library at all, if you want to use jquery as well then you need to use noconflict for jquery. If you don't use jquery then do not include it in your page.

You do need to include mootools for this to work, look at the source of this page 
http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/1-1/showcase/request-html/

And you see that javascripts included look a lot like yours but the first one is: mootools-1.2-core-nc.js

My guess is that's the one your site is missing.

These libraries come from here: http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/ and say you need mootools wich can be found here: http://mootools.net/

Comment: @PhpCoders Ah ok, found it. I think your problem will be solved if you add mootools or remove jquery. Look in the source of the html page generated to check what scripts are loaded and what needs to be added.